# How to change TimePicker Theme color?

Tags: xamarin.forms, colors, timepicker

I have this code to change the theme of the datepicker in my app in styles file in android project:

```
<item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
<style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#039BE5</item>
  </style>
```

Is there a code same to this that can help me for the timepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define style in style.xml

```
<style name="TimePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
 <item name="colorAccent">#039BE5</item>
 <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
 <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

And

```
TimePickerDialog timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(mContext, Resource.style.TimePickerTheme, fromListener, hour, min, false);
```